# Convert a time in different time zone to localtime in Perl?

Tags: perl

Perl built-in function localtime can convert specified date time value to local time, but it doesn't accept time zone number. What is the most easy way to do this transformation for different time zones? Import other modules looks a little complex, especially for one-liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use DateTime.

```
$ perl -MDateTime -E'say DateTime->now( time_zone => $ARGV[0] )' America/Toronto
2015-08-15T18:39:54

$ perl -MDateTime -E'say DateTime->now( time_zone => $ARGV[0] )' America/Halifax
2015-08-15T19:39:55
```

Answer (score 1):

[Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) will respect the TZ environment variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

say scalar localtime->strftime('%F %T %Z');

foreach ('UTC', 'Europe/Paris', 'America/New_York') {
  $ENV{TZ} = $_;
  say scalar localtime->strftime('%F %T %Z');
}
```

Output (when run in London):

```
2015-08-17 09:46:53 BST
2015-08-17 08:46:53 UTC
2015-08-17 10:46:53 CEST
2015-08-17 04:46:53 EDT
```

Comment: This is the just a longer version of the answer the OP already rejected. Windows definitely doesn't know `Europe/Paris`.

Comment: Also, you're supposed to call `POSIX::tzset()` after changing `$ENV{TZ}`.

Answer (score 0):

Localtime() function uses your local system time zone. You can specify timezone  before executing the program using TZ environment variable.

Here is a perl script named time.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $time = localtime;
print $time;
```

output of executing it with and without TZ is following ..

```
./time.pl 
Sun Aug 16 00:12:33 2015 

TZ=GST ./time.pl 
Sat Aug 15 18:42:36 2015
```

Comment: Seems this is only applicable to UNIX-like platform.

Comment: Indeed .. but i presume there must be an env variable in other OS too to change the timezone.

Comment: `TZ` does affect `localtime` on Windows too. Just not sure what values to pass to it. Do note that you're supposed to call `POSIX::tzset()` after changing `$ENV{TZ}`.